# Python - cannot set array value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this piece of code:

```
replMatrix[replMatrix['cat'] == p]['dispersers'] += moving
movers[movers['cat'] == m]['dispersers']= 0
```

but it doesn't work, values don't change, while with this one

```
replMatrix['dispersers'][replMatrix['cat'] == p] += moving
movers['dispersers'][movers['cat'] == m]= 0
```

it works.
So I understand that the right order is

```
array[column][row]
```

and not

```
array[row][column]
```

why , if order seems to be so important, there aren't errors in the first case?

Comment: Does the following work: `replMatrix[replMatrix['cat'] == p, 'dispersers'] += moving` and `movers[movers['cat'] == m, 'dispersers']= 0`?

Comment: Is 'dispersers' picking a field, or picking from a dictionary, or something else?

Comment: Try `movers['dispersers'][movers['cat'] == m] = 0`.

Comment: @BiRico, you seem to be right: changing the code order the values change

Comment: @BiRico: I edited the question, maybe it is not exactly the question you expected, but it seems interesting to me, do you agree?

Comment: I should have pointed this out sooner, but people are very confused by your question because you have not proved them with any sample data. For example @happytrees has written a very nice answer, to a very different question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what the question is asking, but I will say that the order you receive parts of an array does matter.

Rather than picturing 2D arrays as row/column, it is much more represented of them to be though of as nested array.

So if you were to have an array declared something like array[2][2] rather than looking like a grid of 2 by 2, rather look at it like arrays of two in an array of two. In otherwords, the array would look something like: [[1, 2],[3, 4]]. So each subsuquent [] indicates a deeper nesting of the array.

Example: You have an array declared as [[1,2],[3,4]]. It is stored in a variable called array.
If you were to print out array[0], it would output [1,2]. If you were to print out array[0][1], it would output 2.